# Tag standardization for Gods?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is going to be standard for God tags? There is a Shiva tag as [shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiva) and Ganesha tag as [lord-ganesh](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-ganesh).

I mean there should be a standard for this. It's better to remove "lord" from the Ganesha tag or add this to Shiva too. What do you guys think?

Comment: Having tags such as [tag:deity] and [tag:god] are enough I suppose.

Comment: I think there should be tags "lord" and "god", and then other like, "shiva", "vishnu" and so on. We should first use "god" tag and then "shiva" if needed. It'll solve multiple purposes.

Comment: By the way, who has the power to create tag synonyms right now?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan we can request community moderator to do that. But first we need to come to a decision.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Practically speaking, we should wait until pro tempore moderators are picked before requesting tag synonyms - my impression is that the community managers are typically too busy to indulge these requests unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As [Mr_Green suggested](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/tag-standardization-for-gods#comment57_32) to use tags like [deity](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deity) and [god](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god) will be too generalized in my opinion. For example, if a user is interested in lord Ganesha, he will prefer marking the tag of [ganesha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesha) as his favorite.

Also, few users have indepth knowledge of a particular god and hence instead of making the tags generalized, we should make different ones.

Yes, I am aware that Hindu religion have millions of gods and godesses, but again, we shouldn't generalized them. Thus, we can have separate tag wikis as well which will explain specific details for that particular tag.

As far as prefixing the tags is concerned, there's no need of the word `lord`

And to deal with synonyms, we can merge tags like

[ganesha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesha)*(Parent tag)*

[ganesha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ganesha), [siddhivinayak](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siddhivinayak), [ashtvinayak](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashtvinayak) etc as synonyms of their respective parent tag

Comment: I don't think there's a need for the tags for Vishnu and Shiva and the like to have the word "lord" in them.  People can refer to them as "using" lord in their questions and answers if they like, but the tags should be as simple as possible.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes I removed the word lord from tags, I forgot to edit the answer